# Is there a command to move a patch between patch queues?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, mercurial-queue

I realize patch queues have a pretty simple implementation, and you can move stuff manually, but is there a command to move a patch between two queues?

Comment: two queues on the same repo? or between the queues of two repos?

Comment: Two queues on same repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't; you'll have to write an alias for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

To manually do this assuming you have two patch queues "A" and "B" and want to move a patch call "MyPatch" from "A" to "B":

1. Open `.hg/patches-A` directory in repo root
2. Copy `MyPatch` file to `.hg/patches-B` directory
3. Open `.hg/patches-A/series` in text editor and **delete** "MyPatch" line
4. Open `.hg/patches-B/series` in text editor and **add** "MyPatch" line

The `series` file within each patch queue directory contains the names of all patch files within that patch queue.

This is a good candidate for automation via either contributing to the `mq` extension or creating your own extension or shell script.